# Pass selected row one gridview to another gridview on another form

Tags: c#

```
private void btnpass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Inventory coo = new Inventory(
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
    coo.Show();
}
```

I tried to pass the selected row `GridView` to another `GridView` on another form but I get an error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

I used a different method but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

your error message show that there is no row in grid or not any of rows selected

first of all check for selected rows if it was greater than zero then do your job
like this :

```
if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count>0)
{ 
 Inventory coo = new Inventory(
 dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
 dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), 
 dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), 
 dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), 
 dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), 
 dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), 
 dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString()
 ); 
 coo.Show();
}
```